# Java - Mysql Exceptions are not unicode

Tags: java, mysql, exception, unicode

I'm writing a java Gui and everything works good! My only problem is that when i get a mysql exception it looks likes this....

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`,`Î—ÎœÎ•Î¡ÎŸÎœÎ—Î�Î™Î‘ Î“Î•Î�Î�Î—Î£Î—Î£`,`Î£Î¤ÎŸÎ™Î§Î•Î™Î‘ Î¤Î‘Î¥Î¤ÎŸÎ¤Î—Î¤Î‘Î£' at line 1

My database and all the tables and data are written in Greek! I don't have any problems when i select , insert and modify i only get it when it throws an exception! In the begining i thought it was the console's fault of the eclipe so i managed to be utf-8 but when i pass the exception to a message box i have the same problem. I also use for the connection  getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+host+"/db_name?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8",username, password);"

Any good thoughts?? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in the MySQL JDBC connector. The statement is encoded on the way out to the server using the connection encoding (UTF-8 in your case), but the error on the way back in is decoded using the platformEncoding (Java `file.encoding`, looks like ISO-8859-1 or cp1252 in your case).

You may be able to work around it by making sure your default encoding is UTF-8, although in general anything relying on the default encoding is a bad thing. Or of course using ASCII-only schema names.

Comment: Thank you!! My default enconfing is UTF-8 so i don't think there is a problem with that..Thankfully the fault is only when there is an exception and not at the program!! Any other thoughts?